# VBA XML V6.0 How to make wait Table load?

Tags: excel, vba

please. I want to get all data Table from This site web : https://tinfoil.io/Title/
(I use excel VBA and I want lists of games)
Problem: the table is loaded after site load complete and the web site responseText is empty.

```
Sub BasicGETRequest()
    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim reqURL As String
    
    reqURL = "https://tinfoil.io/Title/"
    
    req.Open "GET", reqURL, False
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    req.send
    
    Debug.Print req.readyState
    
    While Not req.readyState = 4
        Debug.Print req.readyState
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:30")
    Wend
    
    If req.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox req.Status & " - " & req.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SaveHTMFile req.responseText
    ParseSiteTitles req.responseText
End Sub

Sub ParseSiteTitles(HTMLString As String)
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Table As MSHTML.IHTMLTable
    Dim Titles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection          'WolVideos
    Dim Title As MSHTML.IHTMLElement                     'WolVideo
    Dim TitleItem As MSHTML.IHTMLElement                 'WolVideoItem
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Long
    Dim hrefText As String                               'hrefText
    Dim Feuil As Worksheet                               'OutputSheet
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerText = HTMLString
    Set Table = HTMLDoc.getElementById
    
    If Titles.Length = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set Feuil = Worksheets.Add
    
    With Feuil
        .Range("A1").Value = "Name"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Publisher"
        .Range("C1").Value = "Size"
        .Range("D1").Value = "Release"
        .Range("E1").Value = "ID"
        .Range("F1").Value = "Hours"
        .Range("G1").Value = "Rating"
        .Range("A1:G1").Interior.Color = rgbCornflowerBlue
        .Range("A1:G1").Font.Color = rgbWhite
        .Range("A1:G1").Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

pleae help Me.
Thank you

Comment: You can get all 8093 titles as a JSON with this URL in one download. I leave all parameters in, also the empty ones. I don't know what the last number stands for but you can get the same list by deliting all parameters from ? till the end: https://tinfoil.media/Title/ApiJson/?rating_content=&language=&category=&region=us&rating=0&_=1654689519694

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider PowerQuery instead, then the M code below would work

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://tinfoil.media/Title/ApiJson/?rating_content=&language=&category=&region=us&rating=0")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"id", "name", "release_date", "publisher", "size", "playtime", "user_rating"}, {"id", "name.1", "release_date", "publisher", "size", "playtime", "user_rating"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Expanded Value1", "name.1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({""">"}, QuoteStyle.None, false), {"name.1.1", "name.1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"name.1.1", type text}, {"name.1.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"name.1.1"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "name.1.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"</a>"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"name.1.2.1", "name.1.2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"name.1.2.1", type text}, {"name.1.2.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"name.1.2.2", "Name"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

(if you're not familiar with PowerQuery then on the *Data* tab of the ribbon, click (i) *Get Data-> From Other Sources -> Blank Query* which will launch the PowerQuery editor where you should click on (ii) the *View* tab, and then (iii) the *Advanced Editor* which opens (iv) a window where you can paste the code:
[image: Screenshot illustrating where the syntax should be written]
)

If you must use VBA then then you may be able to use the direct URL

```
https://tinfoil.media/Title/ApiJson/?rating_content=&language=&category=&region=us&rating=0
```

but, since it returns a JSON result, you'll probably have a lot of tweaking to do.

Comment: Is this VB.Net? Please note: OP is asking on VBA.

Comment: @Parfait no, it's the language of PowerQuery, which is a tool within Excel (since the 2010 version) and the more efficient (than VBA) means to extract web data

Comment: Interesting! Please show _how_ to run what you posted. I was unaware you can write code. Oh I see *Advanced Editor*!